# Magento Login Function

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

Can someone point me in the right direction

I want to have a new login function for my Magento Site.

at present the customer menu has been overridden to www.mysite.com/myaccount

but when users login it keeps showing as customer/account/login.

How to I override the login function to have it as myaccount/login

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the redirect URL specified in the log-in logic.